# How to draw the network diagram

Tags: critical-path

[image]

Hi guys can i get a bit of help here im having a hard time drawing this diagram

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with? Did you start? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Thanks for answering. https://prnt.sc/17hej29 i did start and tried to finish however im unsure about this diagram because of G and F

Comment: Looks like a homework question.

Comment: If you're just drawing the diagram, ignore the durations.  You only need those to calculate early and late start and finishes and the critical path.  Just connect the nodes based on the dependencies.

Comment: Please don't use external links. PMSE supports inline images, as well as code blocks for DOT and other graphics-generating code. External links create bit rot, and go against our community standards. Please include whatever image you are referring to, along with any markup or comments about it, in your original post.

Answer (score 0):

### Dummy tasks of zero duration are needed to handle some situations in Arrow Diagrams

Welcome to PMSE!

What you are drawing is an 'Event on Node Diagram' also known as an 'Arrow Diagram'.

Activity G cannot start until both D and E are complete. However, F can start as soon as E is complete, but need not wait for D. In this situation you need an event to show that E is complete and another event to show that both D and E are complete. You can use a dummy task of zero duration to connect these two (drawn using dotted lines).

See the second bullet point under [Look for the three common problem situations below and redraw them using "dummies" (not real tasks)](https://asq.org/quality-resources/arrow-diagram)